# scilab "warning adding a matrix with the empty matrix will give an empty matrix"

Tags: interpolation, scilab

i am currently designing a scilab code for newton's interpolation method. please see where the error is. I have attached the code and the output error

```
x=[1 3 5 7]
y=[24 120 336 720]
h=x(2)-x(1)
n=length(x)
disp(h)
disp(n)
for i=0:n-1
    d=diff(y,i)
    disp(d)
end
xi=input("value to be interpolated:")
p=(xi-x(1))/h
q=p
y=y(1)
for j=1:n
    s=diff(y,j)
    y=y+(q*s(1))/factorial(j)
    q=q*(p-j)
    
end
disp("the interpolated value is:",y)
```

error:

operation +: Warning adding a matrix with the empty matrix will give an empty matrix result.

Comment: Why using the tags `python`, `C++` and `matlab`? There is definitely nothing dealing with these here.

Comment: @samuel: I removed the irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 1):

To debug this kind of situation, set

```
--> warning stop
```

to turn the warning into a proper error with its message displaying the line number where it occurs. Then we get

```
operation +: Warning adding a matrix with the empty matrix will give an empty matrix result.
at line    17 of executed file C:\scriptPath\test.sce

*** Execution stopped after a warning. ***
Set warning("on") to continue execution after a warning.
```

Line #17 is `y=y+(q*s(1))/factorial(j)`

Then in the script, replace this line with a try/catch block

```
try
    y=y+(q*s(1))/factorial(j)
catch
    pause
end
```

Then rerun the code. At the pause, display each involved variable.
Here we see that `s` is `[]`. This is quite expected since `y=y(1)` initializes it as a scalar. Then when you compute the differences (even only of order 1) from a scalar, you get [].

Then, `q*s(1)` yields `[]`, as well as `q*s(1)/factorial(j)`, and finally the addition `y+[]` yields the warning (or error).